# how to make a php article counter?

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, counter

I write some simple article scripts. Now I want add some article counter.

If there have 3 possibility it should make an article counter.

1. the article has been opened for read.(only one whole article per page, it will count 1 time)
2. the article has been searched in a content search list(with title and short content description 5 items per page, it will count 1 time. then if open to read whole article content, it will count another 1 time.)
3. the article has been showed in the home page by Random (with title and short description, it will count 1 time)

Is there any good suggestion how to do these better?

Which database design is better? put article and count number in one table? or make two tables?

Can anyone recommend me some `php article counter script`, if the main rules write into a file like `class.php` then include into my every page.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `article`? Some sort of post from a message board for example?

Comment: @Nicolás, not short message, but some blog or information articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use the database that auto increments and just increment that value when the page is viewed, and display that value if you want.

Here is how you can setup the [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Then update the "value" (you don't have to actually update anything it will AI)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE COUNTER SET HITS = ''");
```

Then just display the view

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PAGEVIEWS");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['COUNTER'];
  }
```

This is off the top of my head - it should work.

Comment: @mazzzzz, just easy use `update`? I know if there is one article per page, `mysql_query("UPDATE COUNTER SET HITS = '' AND ID= '".$row['id']."'");` but how to update if there is a search page? 5 result per page. the id number is not continued. And is it necessary make another db table to save COUNTER number? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want these results to be private or displayed to the visitors - If not have you looked at [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).  I assume these articles are in a DB...why not just add a counter field to each one and anytime you display it you update that field?? Am I closer to what you want?

Answer (score 3):

If you are counting the number of hits on an article, create a column and add one to it every time somebody accesses the page.

Something like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET count=count+1 WHERE id='$id'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Would increment the column `count` in the table `table` by 1.  Then you could just retrieve that value.