# How to know how many times certain page had referral click to another page?

Tags: php, mysql, click, counter

How to know how many times certain page had referral clicks to another page? I need something which counts the number of clicks on a page within domain. PHP or MySQL, or something else?

Comment: See the Q&A's here => http://stackoverflow.com/q/5985462/ which will give you a general idea. Mostly [**the last answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5985670/) in that page.

Comment: Thank you, Fred -ii-. It will be of use for now.

Comment: You're quite welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does the trick, otherwise you need to log each page click and the referrer address in a database. There's also plenty of applications for that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Can you tell me for some such application?

Comment: No, this is where you need to research this yourself, there are literally hundreds of solutions on the net to this exact problem, as well as dozens of potential solutions you could make yourself. Use Google Analytics.

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an "answer" then. This should have been a comment if you can't help the OP out any further with suggestions other than Google Analytics. (*I know, you don't have enough rep points*)